# How do I reset all my internal DNS settings?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, domain-controller

I am against the wall here with my internal domain.  DNS is a giant mess and I don't know how to deal with it.  I am running a Windows Server 2003 domain.  My primary domain controller handles DHCP, DNS, and group policy.  Here are the symptoms:

1. DNS Event Log is filled with error 6702
2. DNS is not cleaning up its records.  For example, last night I formatted a computer and gave it a different name.  DNS had records for both names under the same IP address.
3. DNS Reverse lookup is not syncing with the forward lookup.
4. DNS is not replicating with backup domain controllers no matter now many times I follow the correct steps to set it up.

At the moment, my backup domain controller is disabled until I can figure out what is going on.  I will be monitoring serverfault and reporting any progress from other advice that I get and I will actively be answering questions anyone has in response to this.

Answer (score 3):

### DNS Event Log is filled with error 6702

You are likely having issues with your DNS master / slave configuration. Since you've got the backup controller offline, address that after determining the cause of your other issues. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842006

### DNS is not cleaning up its records.

> For example, last night I formatted a computer and gave it a different name. DNS had records for both names under the same IP address.

It may be the case that forward lookup hasn't timed out. DHCP would have added a forward record and replaced the reverse lookup record. It wouldn't know to end the other forward lookup record unless that expired its DHCP lease or was released.

### DNS Reverse lookup is not syncing with the forward lookup.

I understand that your forward lookup has entries for `oldname` and `newname`. If you reverse lookup points to `newname`, then all is well. If it points to `oldname`, then we've got some work ahead of us. Please clarify.

### DNS is not replicating

> ...with backup domain controllers no matter now many times I follow the correct steps to set it up.

Check the troubleshooting steps under 6702 from the Knowledge Base article linked above.

Comment: 1)  I will browse through that KB article after I answer you.
2)  I don't know what to do with that information you just gave me.
3)  To clarify using the example from the format I did last night:  The computer's name and IP address showed up in the forward lookup zone (and the original name with the same IP address was still there) and there was no record at all for the IP address in the reverse lookup zone.
4) Reading KB article now.

Thank you so far by the way :)

Comment: Psst!  Remember that by default in an all-Windows-NT-5.x/6.x shop the DHCP _server_ will be registering the address→name mappings via dynamic DNS Update and the DHCP _clients_ will be registering the name→address mappings.